# Laravel Query Builder: Join Tables and Group by id

Tags: mysql, laravel-6

I want to join the following tables and group them by term id, but it seems like there is an error in the SELECT part of my query. Can anyone help me out fixing it?

```
public function getSponsor()
{
    $sponsor = DB::table('sponsors')
        ->join('terms', 'terms.id', '=', 'sponsors.term_id')
        ->join('committees', 'committees.id', '=', 'terms.committee_id')
        ->join('persons', 'persons.id', '=', 'sponsors.person_id')
        ->select('sponsors.term_id as sponsor_term_id', 'terms.id as term_id', 'terms.term', 'persons.person_name', 'persons.id as person_id', 'committees.committee_name')
        ->groupBy('terms.id')
        ->get();

    return $sponsor;
}
```

Here is the error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #4
> of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
> column 'cdorts.persons.person_name' which is not functionally
> dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
> sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `sponsors`.`term_id` as
> `sponsor_term_id`, `terms`.`id` as `term_id`, `terms`.`term`,
> `persons`.`person_name`, `persons`.`id` as `person_id`,
> `committees`.`committee_name` from `sponsors` inner join `terms` on
> `terms`.`id` = `sponsors`.`term_id` inner join `committees` on
> `committees`.`id` = `terms`.`committee_id` inner join `persons` on
> `persons`.`id` = `sponsors`.`person_id` group by `terms`.`id`)

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with a working query in raw sql, and then try to figure out how to reverse engineer that into laravel

Comment: there is anot an error per se, it it is that your mysql server has the option only_full_group_by  enbaled so that line your slect aren't allowed anmyore, because they doesn't male any sense, because you don't define a strategy when there are **more than one* sponsors.term_id. so if you keep the option enabled, every cloumn that is not in the GROUP BY must have a https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Well, I think it's erroneous to include a GROUP BY clause in a query absent of any aggregating functions.